# JForex 3 with Scala & SBT

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use the JForex-3 SDK from Scala / SBT.

My build.sbt looks like:

```
name := "tmp"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

resolvers += "Dukascopy" at "https://www.dukascopy.com/client/jforexlib/publicrepo/"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.dukascopy.dds2" % "DDS2-jClient-JForex" % "3.1.2",
  "com.dukascopy.api" % "JForex-API" % "2.13.30"
)
```

When importing `import com.dukascopy.api.system` there is only "tester" available. I cannot figure out what happens with the rest https://www.dukascopy.com/client/javadoc3/

Can someone help here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading the version of the first library dependency solves the problem. Downgrade it to version 3.0.18

```
name := "tmp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

resolvers += "Dukascopy" at "https://www.dukascopy.com/client/jforexlib/publicrepo/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.dukascopy.dds2" % "DDS2-jClient-JForex" % "3.0.18",
  "com.dukascopy.api" % "JForex-API" % "2.13.30"
)
```